# Instance Variable Syntax Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When declaring an instance variable, does it make a difference if I declare it under @interface and as a @property? Example:

```
   @interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
        NSString *myString;
   }
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
```

Would it matter if I took out the one under @interface? I have been doing that and would like to know if it does anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a modern compiler (recent versions of LLVM), there is no need to declare the instance variables in conjunction with an @property (as tc says; it is the @synthesize that actually tells the compiler to reserve a slot, otherwise, you are on your own for storage) and doing so doesn't change anything.

One suggestion;  when you @synthesize, do something like `@synthesize myString = myString_;` to cause the iVar to have a different name and, thus, make it impossible to accidentally directly access when you meant to go through the property.

Comment: so when using @synthesize myString = _myString; you don't even need to declare _myString in the .h? I didn't know that, pretty awesome.

Comment: Correct;  the compiler will happily synthesize the iVar for you and you can use it directly in your .m, when needed (typically, in `init` and `dealloc`).

Comment: Nitpick: Strictly, it's @synthesize which creates the ivar, not @property. As a result, you can prevent direct access to the ivar by @synthesizing ivars just before @end (although this is not particularly useful).

Comment: A practical difficulty is that the current releases of XCode don't show properties without explicitly-declared ivars in the debugger. They're fine in command-line gdb though.

Comment: Yah -- bummer, that.   Please file a bug.  It'll be a dupe, but also a reminder of how important the bug is to fix.

Comment: I did submit a bug when I first came across this. My comment above was carefully-worded in view of the NDA, but I do *suspect* that a fix may be afoot.

Comment: Thank you for filing the bug (and following the NDA).  Very much appreciated!

Comment: I also submitted a bug report.